# C/C++ plugins behave differently in MacOS and Windows

Tags: c++, vscode-extensions

I'm using the VS Code remote plugin on my MacBook to connect to a remote Ubuntu development machine for a CPP project. The CPP project is based on the trpc framework and is built using Bazel. I'm using the C/C++ plugin for development assistance. When working on my MacBook, the plugin throws numerous errors due to its inability to recognize the header files generated by the framework. This results in the inability to perform code navigation, autocompletion, and other related functionalities. However, when I switch to a Windows computer and use the VS Code remote plugin to connect to the same server for the same project, the C/C++ plugin works seamlessly, allowing for code navigation and autocompletion. I dont know why.

When using Windows, I can view function prototypes and navigate to definitions like this.

[image]

However, on my MacBook, there is no response whatsoever.

[image]

I just wish I had the same experience on my macbook that I had on windows.